# VBA Excel 2010 Run-time Error 1004 - Application-defined or Object-defined Error

Tags: excel, runtime-error, vba

I am a new analyst working on a Macro-enabled worksheet. I ran into some rather popular run-time error while trying to run my macros (i.e., create, delete) multiple times on the same worksheet. I research on the internet and found that the error occurred because my object/variable has not been released every time I re-run the macro. The quick workaround is that I save my worksheet every time I make a change before I run the macros; however, there seems to be a better solution that would get rid of this problem entirely by changing the code to "re-define" my objects every I run the macros. Since I am pretty new to VBA, I am seeking some help with the below lines of code:

```
Sub Delete_Icons()

  ' INTERSECT COMMAND DETERMINES IF A SHAPE EXISTS WITHIN A SPECIFIED RANGE.

  ' IF THERE IS A SHAPE WITHIN ROWS 3 AND 1000 THEN IT WILL BE DELETED.

  ' THIS DOES NOT DELETE THE MACRO BUTTON IN ROWS 1 AND 2.

    Dim shp As Shape

    For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes

        *' this below line caused run-time error 1004*
        **If Not Intersect(shp.TopLeftCell, Range("A3:F1000")) Is Nothing Then**   
         shp.Delete
        End If
    Next shp
```

Any help to fix the run-time error in this line of code would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If the purpose here is just to avoid deleting some specific shapes then you could simplify things down to just testing the names. So the test within the `For Each` loop could just be `If shp.Name <> "foo" Then`

Answer (score 0):

The `Intersect` functions is defined for 2 instances of a `Range` object, and not a `Range` and a `Shape`

Try something like this:

```
Dim shp As Shape, rng As Range
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

    For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.Shapes.Count
        Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes(i)
        For j = 1 To ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range.Count
            Set rng = ActiveSheet.Shapes(i).Range
            ' this below line caused run-time error 1004*
            If Not Intersect(rng, Range("A3:F1000")) Is Nothing Then
             shp.Delete
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
```